# nTop Graphing Scripts

Tags: python, rrdtool, ntop

I would like to graph the RRD files that nTop creates, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

### What I Know

- There is an API for nTop that involves python. I have read the details of it yet.
- I know that nTop is open-source, but it is written in C which I'm unfamiliar with.

### What I Don't Know

- Is it difficult to write your own script?
- Can you re-use a lot of the nTop source code?
- How difficult is it to use rrdtool for graphing?
- Should I just be using XML dumps?

### The Details

Basically, I'm trying to work around the fact that nTop does have a hard limit in terms of rrd database size. What I'd like to do is when the database reaches (or exceeds) a certain size is to rename it "rrd2", thus forcing the tool to recreate it's database. With "rrd2", I can export it or compress it or delete it if it turns out that it isn't useful to keep data that long. The problem is, after you stop nTop, you can't tell it to open an old rrd file to graph it for you (well, at least I can't tell it to do that).

Links, terms to google (I'm out of ideas) and hard doses of reality are greatly appreciated.